# What card readers support Java Card?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard

I Was doing a research on Java Card 3.0 Technology. Basically the requirement is to read smart card details from web browser through Java applet using Java Card. My question is whether Java Card supports all smart card reader or only specific model of devices? Just want to buy the right device which supports Java Card technology

I search over Google couldn't find the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can communicate with a Smart Card or similar device (including a Java Card Smart Card, an NFC-enabled phone..) on any platform with a working implementation of PC/SC (Winscard, PCSC-Lite..), and a working PC/SC reader supporting the interface used by the Smart Card (ISO 7816-3, ISO 14443, variants therof..).

Virtually all Smart Card readers are PC/SC compatible (the few exceptions are either antiques, or very specialized, e.g. testing tools). There is not such thing as one with specific support for Java Card Smart Cards.

The program communicating with the Smart Card could be a native program built on top of PC/SC, or a Java program using the [package `javax.smartcardio`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html) built into Java since the JRE release (1.)6. Java Card is not required for reader-side development (though it may contain useful additional layers that I do not know).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-final list for starters:

http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid/section.html

JavaCard is a ISO7816 smart card as any other, thus all standard smart card readers work. CCID is the common USB standard, which signals cross-platform support.

Just pick one from the above list which does not have anything "red" marked next to it.

Comment: Java Card does not imply ISO 7816-3 (contacts). There are Java Card Smart Cards with ISO 14443 interface only (contactless), and others with dual interface. Increasingly, there's also SWP.

Comment: No it does not imply that. That's why there are also contactless-only and dual interface readers and on the USB level CCID is still the only standard that exists and what to look for (especially if you happen to use anything that's not Windows)

With a question with such level of detail ("a reader for javacard for reading card details") the answer should be sufficient.

Comment: And for nitpicking: PC/SC is (in practical terms) a software API rather than something that reader hardware conforms to. CCID on the other hand is a hardware-level standard.

You can build a PC/SC driver for almost anything, but in real life you depend on vendor drivers. If you want to get vendor-lockin and proprietary hardware and software, look for "PC/SC" suport. Otherwise look for CCID conformance (and some unnamed vendors from the internet could still sell you dysfunctional stuff)